# Upload multiple data by excel sheet in database. 

Tags: asp.net, database, excel

Hey Guys I have a database with field
 `Name,Email,Contact,Address,Profile` And I have created a excel sheet with
 these field & data in it (100 entry).
    Now i want to use File-upload Control for browsing these excel sheet & on click of Button Control it automatically fill excel sheet data into database.

So anybody who has a idea kindly share with me. I try over it a lot but doesn't reach to solution. So please kindly share your valuable guidance.

Comment: Does it have to be Excel format, or can it be a CSV?  The latter is a _lot_ easier to read the data.  For the former, however, it's going to depend on what Excel format you're using.  Different versions have _very_ different file formats.

Comment: Ya its a .csv format, but how can we do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) project.  With this you can very easily dump an Excel file (either older binary format or newer OpenXML format) into a `DataSet`, at which point you can do whatever you want with the data.  Here's some sample code I used as a proof of concept in a previous project:

```
private static DataSet ImportDataFromExcelFile()
{
    DataSet dataFromExcelFile = null;

    // Try importing the file as OpenXML
    using (var excelFile = File.Open(excelFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(excelFile))
        {
            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            dataFromExcelFile = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        }
    }

    if (dataFromExcelFile != null)
        return dataFromExcelFile;

    // Try importing the file as Excel 97-2003
    using (var excelFile = File.Open(excelFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(excelFile))
        {
            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            dataFromExcelFile = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        }
    }

    if (dataFromExcelFile != null)
        return dataFromExcelFile;

    throw new Exception("Unable to determine format of Excel file.");
}
```

First it tries to read the Excel file in the more modern format.  If that fails, it tries in an older format.  If that fails, it gives up and throws an exception.

Comment: Hi david thanks a lot for ur answer, but what i do if data in .csv format & i want to save into sql database. Please advice me.